# Is my analysis approach and decision valid?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I'm busy with a class assignment and I would appreciate a second pair of eyes on my analysis approach. A part of me feels that I'm overthinking this or have done an unnecessary test.

**Context:** Use 4 different methods to process rows of data and measure the time taken in seconds to complete each row (n = 1094)

**Sample of output data:** (Stack really needs a way to draw tables) 
Method 1: Method 2: Method 3: Method 4:
0.131, 0.493, 0.17, 0.123
0.493, 0.678, 0.651, 0.466
0.694, 0.715, 0.53, 0.475
etc...

**My statistical analysis approach:**
I need to measure if there is a statistically significant difference between the means of the methods.

First step I did was test for normality using Shapiro-Wilk. There is a significant result indicating that the data is not normally distributed W = 0.905, p < 0.05

I then used Kruskal-Wallis to determine if the results are statistically significant. The results are statistically significant. F(3, 4376) = 2822.122, p < 0.05

**What I need guidance on or correction:**
I need to select which method performs the "best" and then justify why.

I have chosen Method 3 because while all of the methods measure the same metric (Time to completion in seconds), Method 3 has the **lowest standard deviation** (0.048) but only the second lowest Mean (0.096)

Is it justified to select a method based on its standard deviation even though the methods are statistically significant from each other?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you have any more guidance on what "best" means? Your method with the low standard deviation could perform better under worst-case-scenario conditions, but won't perform as well on average as the method with lower mean. Depending on the application, either one could be preferable. A random server farm would probably prefer the lower average, but time-sensitive applications like nuclear reactor control would probably prefer to ensure that processing is always completed within X seconds, even if it takes longer on average.

Comment: You make a good point. Time-sensitive applications are more applicable to my test. If I understand you correctly, selecting a lower standard deviation is preferable?

Comment: Possibly, but you'd have to compare the numerical differences in mean and SD, since a big increase in mean may not be offset by a slight decrease in SD. One way to look at this would be to fix a threshold value of 0.5s, for example, and see how often each method finishes within the time limit. If you can show that the higher-mean method never exceeds the limit but the lower-mean method does, I think that's a good argument for the higher-mean method in time-sensitive applications.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. I did a test following your example, triple checked my results and the results show a good argument for the higher-mean method. Thank you!